# Testing hover style CSS changes with 'vue-test-utils'

Tags: css, vue.js

I'd like to write tests for a Vue component which looks something like this

HTML

```html
<div>
  <div class="root">
    Hover here.
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
    Tooltip content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.tooltip { visibility: hidden; }
.root:hover + .tooltip { visibility: visible; }
```

So implementing a tooltip with CSS and not DOM events like `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

How could I trigger the hovering event using `vue-test-utils` ?